# creating a date object with only year as an parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

JavaScript

```
 D= new Date('2015');
```

in chrome browser, date is created successfully. but throws an error in safari, it shows invalidDate in safari browser.

I want to create a date with only year parameter as an input to date creating object and it should work in safari browser

Answer (score 1):

If you do not worry about month and day, try to hardcode them. for example

```
var year = '2015';
var d = new Date('01/01' + year);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have only the year, a Date instance has to have everything. You can make up the month and day:

```
var D = new Date(2015, 0, 1); // 1 Jan 2015
```

Note that those parameters are numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

If so, Google Chrome does it wrong.

The specs

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Further reading: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor